# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv giving invalid slice error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export

I am a little baffled as to what is causing this error. A very simple example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"var1" : [1], "var2": [5]})
df.to_csv("csv_file.csv")
```

gives me the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1136, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1171, in save
    self._save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1277, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1289, in _save_chunk
    date_format=self.date_format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 552, in to_native_types
    values = values[:, slicer]
IndexError: invalid slice
```

Anyone else encountered this error before?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the definition of df.  Use the following:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"var1" : [1], "var2": [5]})
```

You need `:` instead of `,` for `var2`.

Comment: Yes, try to define df as I did, and then you'll be able to serialize.